# Determine if a branch is remote or local (using JGit)?

Tags: git, jgit

Is there any way to determine if a branch is a remote or local branch (or both) using JGit? I have:

```
Map<String, Ref> allRefs = git.getRepository().getAllRefs();
Collection<Ref> values = allRefs.values();
for (Ref ref : values) {
  refs.add(ref.getName());
}
```

which gives:

```
HEAD
refs/heads/tmp01
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/newFeatureBranch
refs/heads/sampleBranch
refs/remotes/origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/newFeatureBranch
```

So **newFeatureBranch** is both a local and remote branch. Currently I check if ref.getName() contains "remotes/origin". But is there a better way to determine if a branch is remote or local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "local branches" usually refers to refs in refs/heads.
The term "remote branches" usually refers to refs in refs/remotes.

To list only local branches you use:
`git branch` or `git.branchList().call()`

To list only remote branches you use:
`git branch -r` or `git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.REMOTE).call()`

To list both local and remote branches use:
`git branch -a` or `git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.All).call()`

The corresponding code from [ListBranchCommand.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListBranchCommand.java#L96-104) reads:

```
if (listMode == null) {
        refList = repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs(Constants.R_HEADS);
} else if (listMode == ListMode.REMOTE) {
        refList = repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs(Constants.R_REMOTES);
} else {
        refList = new HashMap<String,Ref>(repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs(
                        Constants.R_HEADS));
        refList.putAll(repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs(
                        Constants.R_REMOTES));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In git all branches are local ones. They all live in the local repository in `.git/refs` and are all just a pointer to a local commit.

What you call a "remote branch" is just a local branch created by `git fetch`.

How those "remote branches" are called is determined by `git config remote.origin.fetch`, which will usually simply tell `git fetch` to create a ref with name `refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Hence checking for the prefix of the name of the ref is exactly the right way.

Comment: ok but as I understand 'harpun' suggestions is also correct. I have not been able to find a corresponding way to iterate only LOCAL branches with       Map<String, Ref> refList = git.getRepository().getRefDatabase().getRefs(Constants.R_REMOTES);
      ListBranchCommand setListMode = git.branchList().setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.REMOTE);

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to list all remote branches and check whether the branch you're interested in is on this list:

```
List<Ref> remoteBranches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.REMOTE).call()
```

You can find more examples for `branchList()` in the [BranchCommandTest](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest.java) unit tests for JGit.

---

Another option would be getting only remote references from the repository:

```
Map<String, Ref> refList = repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs(Constants.R_REMOTES);
```

See more in [ListBranchCommand](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ListBranchCommand.java).